# Create desktop shortcut with locale change at runtime

Tags: shortcuts, locale, desktop-icons

I have a wine application I need to run in Chinese locale.

It works properly from terminal with:

```
LC_ALL=zh_CN wine '.wine/path_to_program/program.exe'
```

and my desktop shortcut works with Command set to:

```
wine '/home/username/.wine/path_to_program/program.exe'
```

but if I add the `LC_ALL=zh_CN` to the front of the command string it fails to run with message **There was an error launching the application.**

Is there a way to include locale change calls in the shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but you may want to try:

```
env LC_ALL=zh_CN wine '.wine/path_to_program/program.exe'
```

Note:

`zh_CN` enables GB2312 encoding. Is that what you want? Otherwise you should replace it with `zh_CN.UTF-8`.